# Pick out a group of items using linq to xml

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-xml

My head is fuzzled with this. I have an xml doc which has the layout for a grid stored in it. If you notice the columns are stored as "Items" in the XML. I am trying to retrieve each "Item" out of the XML using LINQ but no matter what I do I keep taking on straggler properties that I don't need. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
     <DatagridView>
        <ViewType>DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView</ViewType> 
           <ViewLayout> 
             <property name="Columns" iskey="true" value="9">
                <property name="Item1" isnull="true" iskey="true">
                   <property name="VisibleIndex">0</property> 
                   <property name="Visible">true</property> 
                   <property name="Width">1249</property> 
                   <property name="SummaryItem" isnull="true" iskey="true">
                      <property name="SummaryType">Count</property> 
                      <property name="DisplayFormat">{0}</property> 
                      <property name="FieldName">Comments</property> 
                      <property name="Tag" isnull="true" /> 
                   </property>
                   <property name="Name">colComments</property> 
                   <property name="ColumnEditName" /> 
                   <property name="FieldName">Comments</property> 
                </property>
                <property name="Item2" isnull="true" iskey="true">
                   <property name="VisibleIndex">1</property> 
                   <property name="Visible">true</property> 
                   <property name="Width">197</property> 
                   <property name="Name">colEvent</property> 
                   <property name="ColumnEditName" /> 
                   <property name="FieldName">Event</property> 
                </property>
                ......
```

EDIT:

To be clear, the XML can contain any number of columns represented like so:

```
            <property name="Item2" isnull="true" iskey="true">
               <property name="VisibleIndex">1</property> 
               <property name="Visible">true</property> 
               <property name="Width">197</property> 
               <property name="Name">colEvent</property> 
               <property name="ColumnEditName" /> 
               <property name="FieldName">Event</property> 
            </property>
```

I would like to grab those chunks of data in that same order via XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just get the property elements *directly* beneath "Columns":

```
// TODO: Work out what to do if there are zero or multiple such elements
var columns = xdoc.Descendants("property")
                  .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "Columns")
                  .Single();

var items = columns.Elements("property");

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item {0}", (string) item.Attribute("name"));
    foreach (var property in items.Elements("property"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", (string) item.Attribute("name"),
                          (string) item);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I am doing. but I find it less than optimal. I would like to be able to pull out a collection based on the Item property. as they are the actual columns, all of its descendants are related.

Comment: @deanvmc: It's not clear what you mean, I'm afraid. What are you looking for, exactly? The implementation of a method where you already know the signature you want? If so, what's that signature?

Comment: @deanvmc, you mean you know the structure of the items and you want to take advantage of that, e.g. by returning `IEnumerable<Item>`, where `Item` is a class that contains properties like `VisibleIndex` or `Visible`?

Comment: @deanmvc: Not really - because that's exactly what my `items` value is, isn't it? It's grabbing out the direct descendants of the "name=Columns" element... what do you need that *that* doesn't get you?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I also know the amount of expected structures so I have the ability to say "Item" + Count.ToString() which would give Item1, Item2 and so forth. If that helps?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: In your answer I get each property which I have to further query. I thought I could find each item and pull out its values into a logic structure in one go. Yours works, as does mine but its two steps that I would like to make into one, essentially find the property = Items and pull the values into a collection of logical structures.

Comment: @deanmvc: I'm afraid it's *still* not clear what you really want to see. You could easily create your own `Item` class and give it (say) a constructor taking an `XElement` - you could then use `items.Select(x => new Item(x))` to construct an `IEnumerable<Item>`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That might do it: Where(x => ((string) x.Attribute("name")).StartsWith("Item")) Let me check.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm a dope, I know what your doing now! I'm working in VB but come from C# so in my hurry to change it I didn't notice what you did is exactly what I need., sorry :(